# JUnit test cases not displayed in JMtere when create a tests in simple class file but are displayed when create for JUnit class

Tags: eclipse, junit, jmeter

i wanted to perform load testing on my test cases using JMeter before i was creating a class **(NOT JUNIT CLASS)** and for this class i was adding the JUnit annotations, this project was not displayed under J-Unit sampler (the jar was added in lib/junit folder in J Meter), but when i created a new project and this time i create a JUnit class and loaded this class it worked, my project was displayed in JMeter.

can anyone explain me why this happened?

Comment: Any feedback on answer ? If ok you should accept it so that it's useful to others

Answer (score 0):

Did you check "Search for JUnit 4 annotations":

[image]

Did you add all dependencies to jmeter/lib folder ?

Can you show what your class looks like ?

You can see a working example here:

- https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/f2e65bc2f264d4bd7da83279dbdcf236da6edfe3/src/junit/test/Junit4AnnotationsTest.java

Comment: Yes i checked on  "Search for JUnit 4 annotations" and yes i added all the dependencies.

Comment: import org.junit.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class Example1 {

 @Test
 public void test() {
  WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
  driver.get("http://www.google.com");
  System.out.println("Title : " + driver.getTitle());
 }

}